# TransactionTimedOutException

Tags: java, spring, jooq, spring-transactions

I have next settings in my spring boot application.yml:

```
spring:
  transaction:
    default-timeout: 180s
```

Also, I got next exception during my app excecution in prod evnvironment:

```
**Feb 02 16:25:07** dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionTimedOutException: Transaction timed out: **deadline was Fri Feb 02 16:25:07 2024**
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.jooq_3.14.9.POSTGRES.debug(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.transaction.support.ResourceHolderSupport.checkTransactionTimeout(ResourceHolderSupport.java:155) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.transaction.support.ResourceHolderSupport.getTimeToLiveInMillis(ResourceHolderSupport.java:144) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.transaction.support.ResourceHolderSupport.getTimeToLiveInSeconds(ResourceHolderSupport.java:128) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.applyTimeout(DataSourceUtils.java:341) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.applyTransactionTimeout(DataSourceUtils.java:321) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:243) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy171.prepareStatement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.jooq.impl.ProviderEnabledConnection.prepareStatement(ProviderEnabledConnection.java:109) ~[jooq-3.14.9.jar!/:?]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.jooq.impl.SettingsEnabledConnection.prepareStatement(SettingsEnabledConnection.java:73) ~[jooq-3.14.9.jar!/:?]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.prepare(AbstractResultQuery.java:257) ~[jooq-3.14.9.jar!/:?]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:342) ~[jooq-3.14.9.jar!/:?]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch(AbstractResultQuery.java:332) ~[jooq-3.14.9.jar!/:?]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetch(SelectImpl.java:2880) ~[jooq-3.14.9.jar!/:?]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at com.jarma.bime.watch.repository.EventChronologyRepository.getServiceInvolvedChronologiesByEventId(EventChronologyRepository.java:62) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at com.jarma.bime.watch.repository.EventChronologyRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7e3e7757.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at com.jarma.bime.watch.repository.EventChronologyRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$856deb81.getServiceInvolvedChronologiesByEventId(<generated>) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at com.jarma.bime.watch.service.event.EventChronologyService.getServiceInvolvedChronologiesByEventCardId(EventChronologyService.java:86) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at com.jarma.bime.watch.service.event.EventChronologyService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$dcac1eef.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at com.jarma.bime.watch.service.event.EventChronologyService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a84176fc.getServiceInvolvedChronologiesByEventCardId(<generated>) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at com.jarma.bime.watch.repository.reader.EventReader.read(EventReader.java:108) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]:         at com.jarma.bime.watch.repository.EventCardRepository.lambda$fetch$0(EventCardRepository.java:338) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
..
Feb 02 16:25:07 smko-d-web-01 crime[1749220]:       at com.jarma.bime.watch.service.kis.uss.workers.KisUssUpdateCardByDateWorker.update(KisUssUpdateCardByDateWorker.java:35) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Feb 02 16:25:07 smko-d-web-01 crime[1749220]:       at com.jarma.bime.watch.service.kis.uss.workers.KisUssUpdateCardByDateWorker$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ef67975f.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Feb 02 16:25:07 smko-d-web-01 crime[1749220]:       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
...
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 crime[1749220]:        at com.jarma.bime.watch.service.kis.uss.workers.KisUssWorkerImpl.getCardUpdates(KisUssWorkerImpl.java:123) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 crime[1749220]:        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1220.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 crime[1749220]:        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 crime[1749220]:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 crime[1749220]:        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 crime[1749220]:        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 crime[1749220]:        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy170.getCardUpdates(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 crime[1749220]:        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1220.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 crime[1749220]:        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 crime[1749220]:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 crime[1749220]:        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 crime[1749220]:        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 crime[1749220]:        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:95) [spring-context-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 crime[1749220]:        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 crime[1749220]:        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 crime[1749220]:        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) [?:?]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 crime[1749220]:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
Feb 02 16:25:07 dudna-web-01 crime[1749220]:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
```

Why is the time of **deadline** equals to the time of the **exception**?

**Feb 02 16:25:07 2024** dudna-web-01 bime[1749220]: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionTimedOutException: Transaction timed out: deadline was **Fri Feb 02 16:25:07 2024**

As I understand, both of them must be different and the differense must be 180s

Code of main parts:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */5 * * * *")
public void getCardUpdates() {
updateOrCreateEventCard();
```

...

```
@Transactional
public List<KisUssResponseResult> update(List<KisUssResponseResult> resultLst) {
```

...

```
public List<EventServiceInvolvedChronology> getServiceInvolvedChronologiesByEventId(Long eventId) {
        List<EventServiceInvolvedChronology> result = dsl.select(SERVICE_INVOLVED_CHRONOLOGY.ID, SERVICE.NAME, SERVICE.ID, SERVICE_STATUS.NAME, SERVICE_INVOLVED_CHRONOLOGY.ACTION_DATE)
                .from(SERVICE_INVOLVED_CHRONOLOGY)
                .innerJoin(SERVICE_STATUS).on(SERVICE_STATUS.ID.eq(SERVICE_INVOLVED_CHRONOLOGY.SERVICE_STATUS_ID))
                .innerJoin(SERVICE).on(SERVICE.ID.eq(SERVICE_STATUS.SERVICE_ID))
                .where(SERVICE_INVOLVED_CHRONOLOGY.EVENT_ID.eq(eventId))
                .fetch().map(r -> {
                    EventServiceInvolvedChronology serviceChronology = new EventServiceInvolvedChronology(r.get(SERVICE_INVOLVED_CHRONOLOGY.ID),
                            r.get(SERVICE.NAME), r.get(SERVICE.ID), r.get(SERVICE_STATUS.NAME), r.get(SERVICE_INVOLVED_CHRONOLOGY.ACTION_DATE).toZonedDateTime());
                    return serviceChronology;
                });
        return result;
    }
```

Added versions:

```
<java.version>11</java.version>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.4.13</version>
<jooq.version>3.14.9</jooq.version>
```